# Can php call a static alias?

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation, late-static-binding

In php, is it possible for a method in a parent class to use an alias in a child class from within an instance of the child class?

Parent class:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function getNewFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
use My\Custom\Path\To\Foo;

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

}
```

Code:

```
$child = new ChildClass();
return $child->getNewFoo();
```

I would like this code to return a new instance of `My\Custom\Path\To\Foo()` rather than a new instance of `Foo()`.

I realize I can store the desired path to Foo in a class property, or I can simply instantiate the desired Foo in the child class. However, both of these seem redundant considering the path is already stored in the `use` statement in the child class.

Comment: If the answer is "no, php can't do that partially due to unintended adverse side effects", I would be glad to accept the answer. On the other hand, I was contemplating whether `static::` could instantiate the object using the desired namespace, but `static::` seem to apply to class properties only, and not aliases.

Comment: It's an interesting observation. I've re-worked the comment as an answer.

Comment: Never tried, but is it possible to pass fully qualified class name as a parameter for instantiation?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to instantiate using the desired class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a lot of PHP here. It's supposed to know that your `use` statement is going to impact something in a completely different class, in a completely different file, just because?

If PHP did that by default it would cause a lot of very strange problems for people. Re-define the method, or as you point out, store that property in the class itself.

I think a lot of developers would expect, or at least prefer that PHP behave the way it does.

It sounds like what you need here is a factory function that can be redefined in the subclass to behave differently, or in other words, that `getNewFoo()` should be overridden in the subclass to use the alternate version.